# How to quickly see all sockets listening for IPv4?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I recently [learned that IPv6 sockets can also listen on IPv4 ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152612/netstat-why-are-ipv4-daemons-listening-to-ports-listed-only-in-a-inet6) if `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` is enabled.

So far I have been using `netstat` and `ss` to check what sockets are listening. Since I am often only interested in IPv4 sockets, I used to use to the following command:

```
$ sudo ss -tulpn4
```

but this misses all inet6 sockets listening which also accept IPv4 peers.

Is there a convenient tool that quickly shows all sockets listening on IPv4 ports?